# Issue with processing an xml file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a 5gb xml file which need to be processed.  So, I used `XMLReader`, but I am having hard time with processing files.

I have following part and I want to take the values of `levelid,levelUl,primaryCode,primaryPower` from sections coming under `<ab:pin id="1022">,<ab:pin id="1023">,<ab:pin id="1024">` etc.  But the problem I am now  facing is there are different sections having the same element names like `levelid,levelUl,primaryCode,primaryPower` etc. with different values and I am getting incorrect values.

How do I correct to correct my code?  Following is part of 5 GB xml file

```
 <ab:pin id="1022">
                            <ab:attributes>
                                <ab:levelid>1022</ab:levelid>
                                <ab:levelUl>9837</ab:levelUl>
                                <ab:primaryCode>25</ab:primaryCode>
                                <ab:primaryPower>330</ab:primaryPower>
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                          <ab:pin id="1023">
                            <ab:attributes>
                                <ab:levelid>1023</ab:levelid>
                                <ab:levelUl>9833</ab:levelUl>
                                <ab:primaryCode>35</ab:primaryCode>
                                <ab:primaryPower>340</ab:primaryPower>
```

Following is the code what i have done

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
                reader.MoveToContent();
                string nsUn = reader.LookupNamespace("ab");
                while (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("levelid", nsUn);
                    if (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement cell = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                        level_id = cell.Value;
                        ins3gericson.Add(new TestField("level_id", level_id, 2));
                    }

 reader.ReadToFollowing("levelUl", nsUn);
                    if (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement cell = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                        ins3gericson.Add(new TestField("levelUl", cell.Value, 2));
                    }
 reader.ReadToFollowing("primaryCode", nsUn);
                    if (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement cell = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                        ins3gericson.Add(new TestField("primaryCode", cell.Value, 2));
                    }
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("primaryPower", nsUn);
                    if (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        XElement cell = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                        ins3gericson.Add(new TestField("primaryPower", cell.Value, 2));
                    }
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem? *“Having a hard time”* is not a useful problem statement.

Comment: for example levelid coming under section <ab:pin id="1022"> has value 1022 .But there are other sections with levelid blank value and i am getting blank value instead of 1022

Comment: Are those `ab:pin` elements nested?

Comment: If you are interested in the `ab:pin` elements then read and loop until you hit one, then use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to pull in the element and use LINQ to XML to access the contents without having to depend on the XML reader API.

Comment: @Martin Honnen is that the one i am using or not????i posted my code also

Comment: Yes, but I am suggesting to use the XmlReader to find an `ab:pin` and then use XNode.ReadFrom to pull in the complete element and then to access the children, you seem to try to find children.

Comment: Can you post code snippet for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("input.xml"))
        {
            xr.MoveToContent();
            XNamespace ab = xr.LookupNamespace("ab");
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.NamespaceURI == ab && xr.LocalName == "pin")
                {
                    XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                    var data = from atts in pin.Elements(ab + "attributes") select new {
                        levelid = (string)atts.Element(ab + "levelid"),
                        levelUl = (string)atts.Element(ab + "levelUl"),
                        primaryCode = (string)atts.Element(ab + "primaryCode"),
                        primaryPower = (string)atts.Element(ab + "primaryPower")
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine("levelId: {0}; levelUl: {1}, ...", data.First().levelid, data.First().levelUl); // store/output values here
                }
            }
        }
```

Obviously it all depends on how large the `ab:pin` elements are, but normally with huge XML input the individual elements fit well into memory. And be careful with the XmlReader, if you have adjacent `ab:pin` elements without any whitespace, then the above might skip an element, so there the code would need some more finetuning, along the lines of

```
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("../../XMLFile1.xml"))
        {
            xr.MoveToContent();
            XNamespace ab = xr.LookupNamespace("ab");
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.NamespaceURI == ab && xr.LocalName == "pin")
                {
                    XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                    var data = from atts in pin.Elements(ab + "attributes") select new {
                        levelid = (string)atts.Element(ab + "levelid"),
                        levelUl = (string)atts.Element(ab + "levelUl"),
                        primaryCode = (string)atts.Element(ab + "primaryCode"),
                        primaryPower = (string)atts.Element(ab + "primaryPower")
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine("levelId: {0}; levelUl: {1}, ...", data.First().levelid, data.First().levelUl);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The second sample has an inner `while`, the first an `if`.